# Преобразование числа смещений дробной части числа UNIX C

Tags: c, алгоритм, длинная-арифметика

Создали следующую структуру для хранения больших чисел:

```
typedef enum {
  L_BITS, //младшие биты
  M_BITS, //средние
  H_BITS, //старшие
  S_BITS, //16-23 бит под экспаненту 31 под знак
  ALL_BITS
} e_dec_bit_t;

typedef struct {
  int bits[ALL_BITS];
} my_decimal;

#define INT_BITS sizeof(int) * 8
#define DEC_BITS ALL_BITS * sizeof(int) * 8

#define NEW_DECIMAL(l_b, m_b, h_b, scale, sign) \
  { l_b, m_b, h_b, ((scale << 16) | (sign << 31)) }
```

**S_BITS**

> - Биты от 0 до 15, младшее слово, не используются и должны быть равны нулю;
> - Биты с 16 по 23 должны содержать показатель степени от 0 до 28,    который указывает степень 10 для разделения целого числа;
> - Биты с 24 по 30 не используются и должны быть равны нулю;
> - Бит 31 содержит знак;

---

> Decimal число - это значение с плавающей точкой, состоящее из знака,
> числового значения, где каждая цифра находится в диапазоне от 0 до 9,
> и коэффициента масштабирования, который указывает положение десятичной
> точки, разделяющей целые и дробные части числового значения.
>
> Двоичное представление Decimal состоит из 1-разрядного знака,
> 96-разрядного целого числа и коэффициента масштабирования,
> используемого для деления 96-разрядного целого числа и указания того,
> какая его часть является десятичной дробью. Коэффициент
> масштабирования неявно равен числу 10, возведенному в степень в
> диапазоне от 0 до 28. Следовательно, двоичное представление Decimal
> имеет вид ((от -2^96 до 2^96) / 10^(от 0 до 28)), где -(2^96-1) равно
> минимальному значению, а 2^96-1 равно максимальному значению.

Делю число `5` на `2` в итоге получаю `2.5` или в двоичной форме `10.01`

[image: Представление чисел Decimal]

---

*Вопрос в сдедующем в своей структуре я записываю порядок не в 2, а в 10 форме, как мне число смещений преобразовать в 10 форму, тоесть цифры от 0001 до 1001 в 10 форме имеют scale 1, в 2 от 1 до 4;*

Я думаю сделать это, через изменения степени от 2 к 10 через логарифм. Или есть способ проще и без задействия внешних библиотек.

Смещение от точки записается в scale 16 - 23 bits в форме десятеричной и представляет смещение в форме 2^(1-4) откругляется до числа 1 в десятеричной форме которую я записываю 10^1

---

Мне необходимо найти число `k --> 2^n = 10^k`, где `n` известно.

Comment: Кажется, что 2.5 в двоичной системе это 10.1, а не 10.01.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko  У нас система расчётов иначе, scale степень не с лева на право, а на оборот. А так возможно и ошибочка проверю. Да и вопрос не про то пока.

Comment: да, это не было ответ на вопрос, просто бросилось в глаза. Что касается вопроса, то я его несколько раз перечитал и пока не понимаю. Тип Decimal очень похож на тот, что есть в .NET/C#. Кажется, что это он и есть. Но это всё, что я понял.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Да реализую Decimal из C# в С. А поводу работы деления, я не уверен как именно она должна работать. По всей вероятности ещё будет много работы. Осталась дробная часть и установка степени.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko 2^n уразывает где стоит точка мне нужно найти точку записав в десятичной по основанию 10^k С дальнейшим округлением до целого.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Оказалось в Decimal число 2.65 это тоже самое что 265 только в scale  стоит 2